# Accessor functions for Common Lisp class slots

Tags: class, common-lisp

I'm currently reading the chapter on classes in Peter Seibel's Practical Common Lisp, and I'm confused by the use of [accessor functions](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html#accessor-functions).

### Setf

I don't understand the new definition of the `setf` function given below for the example involving bank accounts and customer names :

```
(defun (setf customer-name) (name account)
  (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) name))
```

It is used as follows:

```
(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")
```

Why does the definition of `setf` take two arguments `(name account)`, but that's not what we provide? And does the `customer-name` function above have anything to do with the `customer-name` reader function defined later (see below)?

```
(defgeneric (setf customer-name) (value account))

(defmethod (setf customer-name) (value (account bank-account))
  (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) value))
```

### Direct slot access

The motivation for accessor functions is to avoid accessing slots directly; interface over implementation and all that. But Common Lisp provides the `:reader`, `:writer`, and `:accessor` slot options to do just that. E.g.

```
(customer-name
 :initarg :customer-name
 :initform (error "Must supply a customer name.")
 :accessor customer-name)
```

Am I correct in understanding that this should only be used for slots that are absolutely OK with being directly accessed? Because if we decide later that the slots *shouldn't* be directly accessed, we'd break things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setf` is a bit magical. The point of `setf` is to make the syntax for setting a value similar to the syntax for accessing that value. For the case where you define a `setf` function using `defun` (or `defmethod`), `(setf (f ...) val)` becomes equivalent to `(funcall #'(setf f) val ...)`. That is why `setf` only takes a single argument in your example; the second argument passed to `(setf customer-name)` is `my-account`. If you want to read more about the internals of `setf`, I wrote a blog post about it which you can find [here](http://malisper.me/2015/09/22/getting-places/).

Because it is so common to write readers and writers to a slot, `defclass` provides the `:reader`, `:writer`, and `:accessor` options. When you pass in one of these options, `defclass` will automatically write the respective readers and writers. For example, the slot definition:

```
(customer-name
  :accessor customer-name
  ...)
```

will automatically write the code:

```
(defgeneric customer-name (account))

(defmethod customer-name ((account bank-account))
  (slot-value account 'customer-name))

(defgeneric (setf customer-name) (value account))

(defmethod (setf customer-name) (value (account bank-account))
  (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) value))
```

for you!

As for your question about accessing slots directly, the most common pattern I have seen is to make accessors for all of the slots, and then only export the accessors for the slots that are supposed to be directly accessible. That way, you can access all of the slots directly from the same package as the class was defined in, but from a different package you can only access the "exported" slots.

Comment: Ah, your explanation about `(setf (f ...) val)` becoming `(funcall #'(setf f) val ...)` is what I was looking for. So I guess that means we didn't *have* to name the function `(setf customer-name)`? We could have named it `(setf foo)` as long as the *definition* still accessed the `customer-name` slot (although we should certainly follow good convention)?

Comment: Yes, but then macros like `incf` wouldn't work on the `customer-name` function.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at your blog post for more information.

Comment: Note also that decision whether to use a method or a slot depends on what you want: a method is basically a function which can evaluate to new results based on the state of the environment, whereas slots are set only ONCE at initialization time and not changed.

Answer (score 2):

**A function as a setter**

> ```
> (defun (setf customer-name) (name account)
>   (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) name))
> ```

`(setf customer-name)` is actually the function name. Yes, in Common Lisp a function name can be a list like that - not only symbols. Parameters are the new `name` and the customer `account`. It then sets the `customer-name` slot in the `account` instance.

> ```
> (setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")
> ```

So you use the accessor form, write a `setf` around it and the new value. Common Lisp then figures out which setter belongs to the accessor form. It's the function you've defined earlier. `my-account` is the object, `"Sally Sue"` is the new `customer-name`.

**A generic function as a setter**

> ```
> (defgeneric (setf customer-name) (value account))
> ```

This defines a similar function like above, but this time it is a CLOS *generic function* and not a normal *function* defined by `defun`. Common Lisp has normal functions and *generic functions*. The latter are a part of the *Common Lisp Object System* and offer features like dynamic multiple dispatch. This generic function would replace any other function definition.

> ```
> (defmethod (setf customer-name) (value (account bank-account))
>   (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) value))
> ```

This defines a method, similar to the function above, but this time it is a method for the generic function named `(setf customer-name)` - remember this list is a function name. This method is defined for all classes of `value` and the `bank-account` class for account. Thus you can only set the customer name of bank accounts (and its subclasses) with it.

**Setters defined in DEFCLASS**

As you mentioned `DEFCLASS` can define the setters by providing the appropriate slot option. That's just a convenience so much of the definition of a class can be in one place.

**Information hiding and other software engineering principles**

When and where you actually use *setter functions* and when you use *direct slot access* is just a matter of style and software engineering principles. Common Lisp makes no restrictions. It's up to you to define the rules which keep your software maintainable. You can also follow the usual best practices for object-oriented software design. Just note that in Common Lisp much is style and convention, as Common Lisp does not have a real module system. It has packages for symbols, but that is not a real module system, since it does not have defined visibility scopes for classes, slots and/or generic functions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about how CL doesn't have a "real module system". My understanding is that we can control what to export from a package, right? The whole difference between one vs. two colons (`foo:bar` vs. `foo::baz`), although we *cannot* restrict the user from accessing `foo::baz` if they really wanted to?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong:  As I said: the package is not about functionality, it is a namespace system for symbols - not a module system. Additionally, as you said, it actually does not restrict access of anything.

Comment: Do you think that a "real module system" would be good/necessary for CL? Given that CL has been standardized by gov't bodies, it appears difficult to add new features/functionality, at least compared to newer languages with community-driven feature development (e.g. Python or Clojure).

Comment: @TianxiangXiong If someone says "real module system", it is as unclear what their personal perception of a "real module system" is as there are opinions on this seasons "real fashion colors". Lets make a poll: "c++20 modules == real module system?" "rust crates == real module system?" "julia packages == RMS?" ... ad lib ad infinitum.